# icon hover doesn't when hovered together with list item anchor - HTML

Tags: html, css

I was trying to create an effect on my nav list items: When the mouse hovers over the list item anchor tags (or even in the active state), the image in the `<span>` should be replaced with a colored version of the image. The color of the text and the color of the icon must be changed together.

The code I am using is below but it this doesn't work. See the difference here: 
**Required result**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCTkd.jpg
**Actual Result**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMRQe.jpg

```css
nav ul li a:hover,
.active {
  color: #3B94D9;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px color #3B94D9;
}

span {
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

span#home {
  width: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url('../img/home.png') no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

span#home:hover {
  background: url('../img/home-hover.png') no-repeat;
}

span#notif {
  width: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url('../img/bell.png') no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

span#notif:hover {
  background: url('../img/bell-hover.png') no-repeat;
}

span#msg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url('../img/messages.png') no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

span#msg:hover {
  background: url('../img/messages-hover.png') no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active"><span id="home"></span> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="notif"></span>Notifications</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="msg"></span>Messages</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, but in your CSS you are targeting the span only when it is directly hovered over. You need to target it when the containing `<a>` is hovered over.

So instead of using:

```
span#home:hover {
  background: url('../img/home-hover.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Use this to target the span when it's container `a` element is in the hover state:

```
a:hover span#home {
  background: url('../img/home-hover.png') no-repeat;
}
```

You can also target the `.active` class this way, i.e. `a.active span#home`

**Working snippet**: 
(Note I've added a block colour in place of the icon because we don't have your images to show them here)

```css
nav ul li a:hover,
.active {
  color: #3B94D9;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px color #3B94D9;
}

span {
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
   }

span#home {
  width: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url('../img/home.png') no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

a.active span#home,
a:hover span#home {
  background: url('../img/home-hover.png') no-repeat;
}

span#notif {
  width: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url('../img/bell.png') no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

a.active span#notif,
a:hover span#notif {
  background: url('../img/bell-hover.png') no-repeat;
}

span#msg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  background: url('../img/messages.png') no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom
}

a.active span#msg,
a:hover span#msg {
  background: url('../img/messages-hover.png') no-repeat;
}

/* added for TESTING ONLY as your images are not visible in the snippet */
span#home, span#notif, span#msg{
  background-color:#eee;
  height: 20px;
  width:20px;
}
a.active span#home, a.active span#notif, a.active span#msg,
a:hover span#home, a:hover span#notif, a:hover span#msg{
  background-color:#3B94D9;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active"><span id="home"></span> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="notif"></span>Notifications</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span id="msg"></span>Messages</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```